# I'm getting PHP Error || PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/westudyu/public_html/register.php on line 73

Tags: php, html

I've checked already the open, ad closed tags  also, If statements, and braces { } and every open brace, has a corresponding closing brace, and vice versa,
but and I don't know why I still receive this error
sorry if the code is long, but this is it, for you to help me overcome this issue,

Thanks in advance, dears

```
    <?php
 include("server.php");
 include("func.php");
?>

<br>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.phptutorial.net/app/css/style.css'>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>



<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        //something was posted
        $user_post = $_POST['username'];
        $user_post = $_POST['password'];
        if (!empty($_username) && !empty($password) && !is_numeric($username))
        {
            $user_id= random_num(20);
            $_query = "insert into wusers (user_id,username,password) values ('$user_id','$username','$password');
            myslqi_query($con, $query);
            header('Location:login.php');
            die;
        }
        else 
        {   
            echo 'please enter valid data';
        }
    }
    else 
    {   
            echo '.';
    }

?>

<main>
    <form action='register.php' method='post'>

        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <div>
            <label for='username'>Username:</label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id='username'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='email'>Email:</label>
            <input type='email' name='email' id='email'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='password'>Password:</label>
            <input type='password' name='password_1' id='password_1'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='password2'>Password Again:</label>
            <input type='password' name='password_2' id='password_2'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='agree'>
                <input type='checkbox' name='agree' id='agree' value='yes'/> I agree
                with the
                <a href='#' title='terms of services'>term of services</a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type='submit'>/Register</button>
        <footer>Already a member? <a href='login.php'>Login here</a></footer>
    </form>
</main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: $user_id= random_num(20);
$_query = "insert into wusers (user_id,username,password) values('$user_id','$username','$password')";
myslqi_query($con, $query);
header('Location:login.php');
die;

Answer (score 1):

Your query quotes are not closed in line:

```
$_query = "insert into wusers (user_id,username,password) values ('$user_id','$username','$password');
```

Be aware that it's also wrong way to do it. Your query may be easly affected by SQL injection attack.